# How to update user information using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement authentication by combining Django Rest Framework and Angular, but I am suffering from user information update.
Angular sends it to Django with the PUT method, Django accepts the request with View "AuthInfoUpdateView".

```
class AuthInfoUpdateView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

At this time, Django accepts the request as below.

```
request.data = {'email': 'test3@example.com', 'username': 'test3', 'profile': 'i am test3'}
request.user = test3@example.com
```

And the serializer is implementing as below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Account, AccountManager

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'profile', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create_user(request_data=validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        insntance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        insntance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        insntance.profile = validated_data.get('profile', instance.profile)
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

I tried to update the user from Angular in such an implementation, and the following response is returned.
`"{"username":["account with this username already exists."],"email":["account with this email address already exists."]}"`

It is thought that it is because you did not specify the record to update, but is there a way to solve it smartly without changing the current configuration so much?
I need your help.

Comment: Which version of django rest framework are you using? From 3.0, `PUT` is always considered as update
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#put-as-create

Comment: @arun i'm using djangorestframework==3.6.3.

Comment: You wrote `insntance` instead of `instance`. If it is not a typo you're not modifying the object that you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
class AuthInfoUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
```

use http method patch can partial_update your instance.

```
method PATCH -> partial update instance 
method PUT -> update instance
```